# jQuery DataTable multi rows header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I used jQuery DataTable to show some data.

Here is my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/naody2fu/3/).

I tried to add collapse/expand using bootstrap collapse functionality.

So I made two rows.

But if you see console it throws an javascript error so code below it not running.

How can I fix this?

**Here is html code:**

```html
<table id="taskTable">
  <thead class="bg-light text-capitalize">
    <tr>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>User</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
      <td>Subject1</td>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>Duration1</td>
      <td>User1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="demo1">
      <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">
      <td>Subject2</td>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td>Duration2</td>
      <td>User2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="demo2">
      <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not feeling good using this approach:
Because of search, the sort, etc will break the concept of `<tr>` as header and it's next `<tr>` as content.

Maybe you can achieve the same thing using a different approach, like you can have child rows [like here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). But you can also fix the above problem as below:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/20rhcq7v/13/)

**HTML**

```
<table id="taskTable">
  <thead class="bg-light text-capitalize">
    <tr>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>User</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <th colspan="4"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
      <td>Subject1</td>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td>Duration1</td>
      <td>User1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="demo1">
      <td colspan="4">aaa</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">
      <td>Subject2</td>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td>Duration2</td>
      <td>User2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="demo2">
      <td colspan="4">aa2</td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
      <td style="display: none;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$("#taskTable").dataTable({
  "ordering": false
});
```

Comment: it works but if this is not right approach, what would you recommend?

Comment: @Guru

If you sort or search, then you might not going to get header first and it's child beneath it. I have also updated the answer.